# following code i am running insiide LongDiv function. But i am getting error LongDiv is not defined

Tags: javascript, php

```
function LoginDiv() {
   var joinAs = document.getElementById('joinAs');
    while(joinAs.firstChild)
              {
                joinAs.removeChild(joinAs.firstChild);
             }
              joinAs.innerHTML= "<div class='form row'><?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array('id'=>'login-form','enableClientValidation'=>true,'clientOptions'=>array('validateOnSubmit'=>true,),)); ?><div id='LoginDiv' class='answer_list' ><div  class='col-lg-12' style='background-color:#F5F5F5;'><div class='row' style='margin:2% 0% 2% 0%'><div align='center' class='col-lg-6'><img src='images/close.png' onclick='hideDiv()' style='width:6%;cursor: pointer'></div><div align='center' class='col-lg-6'><p style='font-size:22px'>LOGIN</p></div></div><div style='clear:both'></div><div align='center' style='width:30%; margin:auto'><form action='' method='POST'><div class='form-group has-feedback'><label for='inputName' class='col-sm-2 col-xs-2 control-label' style='font-weight: 100;'>USERNAME</label><?php echo $form->textField($model,'username'); ?></div><?php echo $form->error($model,'username'); ?><div class='form-group has-feedback'><label for='inputName' class='col-sm-2 col-xs-2 control-label' style='font-weight: 100;'>PASSWORD</label><?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password'); ?></div><?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?><div class='row'><div  class='col-xs-4'><button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat' onclick='PostLogin()'>Sign In</button></div></div></form></div></div></div><?php $this->endWidget(); ?></div>}</script><script src='js/validations.js' ></script></html>";
  }
```

This is script inside `LongDiv()` function, but I am getting following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: LoginDiv is not defined

I search but all I got is you can't run php code inside javascript.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither the title nor the posted code makes any sense at all? Try to at least make an effort in explaining what the issue is ?

Comment: i have added above the whole function now. Please help me solving this issue

Comment: pasted into chrome and tried to run and it picks up that it is a function just fine. On a separate note, why do you have PHP code within JS? there is nothing to run it and will just look odd.

Comment: I am using Yii framework. When i click on login button the LoginDiv gets called. In this I am loading Login Page (designed using Yii framework with php code) using joinAs.innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure of my answer... But you can try it out!!

```
    <script>
    function LoginDiv() {
       var joinAs = document.getElementById('joinAs');
        while(joinAs.firstChild)
                  {
                    joinAs.removeChild(joinAs.firstChild);
                 }

                 var innerText = "<div class='form row'>";
                 innerText += <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array('id'=>'login-form','enableClientValidation'=>true,'clientOptions'=>array('validateOnSubmit'=>true,),)); ?>
                 innerText += " <div id='LoginDiv' class='answer_list' ><div  class='col-lg-12' style='background-color:#F5F5F5;'><div class='row' style='margin:2% 0% 2% 0%'><div align='center' class='col-lg-6'><img src='images/close.png' onclick='hideDiv()' style='width:6%;cursor: pointer'></div><div align='center' class='col-lg-6'><p style='font-size:22px'>LOGIN</p></div></div><div style='clear:both'></div><div align='center' style='width:30%; margin:auto'><form action='' method='POST'><div class='form-group has-feedback'><label for='inputName' class='col-sm-2 col-xs-2 control-label' style='font-weight: 100;'>USERNAME</label>";
                 innerText += <?php echo $form->textField($model,'username'); ?> + "</div>" + <?php echo $form->error($model,'username'); ?>
                 innerText += "<div class='form-group has-feedback'><label for='inputName' class='col-sm-2 col-xs-2 control-label' style='font-weight: 100;'>PASSWORD</label>" + <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password'); ?> +"</div>" + <?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?> + "<div class='row'><div  class='col-xs-4'><button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat' onclick='PostLogin()'>Sign In</button></div></div></form></div></div></div>" + <?php $this->endWidget(); ?> + "</div>";

                 joinAs.innerHTML= innerText;
             }
    </script>
    <script src='js/validations.js' ></script>
    </html>
```

Comment: tried the above code. But not working. Thanks though for helping